# Set a price for IAP Consumable in AppStore Connect API

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm trying to use AppStore Connect API to create and configure a simple pricing for In App Purchase.

### What I want

- I successfully created the IAP using `POST v2/inAppPurchases`
- Now I want to simulate setting the price based in CZK currency as base. Basically I want to replicate these actions in UI

  - **STEP 1 IN UI** - click on Add Pricing in detail of the IAP
  - **STEP 2 IN UI** - Base country: **Czech Republic (CZK)**, Price: **Kč 99.00**
  - **STEP 3 in UI** - **I click Next and then Confirm**. I'm perfectly fine with the currency conversions to other currencies so I don't want to change anything.
- This is how the final result looks in UI
  [image: Final price schedule]

### What I tried

So I followed the official [AppStore Connect docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/app_store/in-app_purchase/managing_in-app_purchases).

- I create the IAP first using `POST v2/inAppPurchases`. I remember the returned IAP ID.
- Now I find the **price point** using `GET /v2/inAppPurchases/{id}/pricePoints` and get its ID.
- Now I call `POST /v1/inAppPurchasePriceSchedules`, I'm following the documentation preciesly but it's not working. The response is complaining about `startDate` and `endDate` and some timelines but I have no idea what these fields should contain. I tried setting it to an empty values or some dates but this is not what the API is expecting.

My request

```json
{
    "data": {
        "type": "inAppPurchasePriceSchedules",
        "relationships": {
            "baseTerritory": {
                "data": {
                    "id": "CZE",
                    "type": "territories"
                }
            },
            "inAppPurchase": {
                "data": {
                    "id": "6477355320",
                    "type": "inAppPurchases"
                }
            },
            "manualPrices": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": "eyJzIjoiNjQ3NzM1NTMyMCIsInQiOiJDWkUiLCJwIjoiMTAwNTEifQ",
                        "type": "inAppPurchasePrices"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "included": [
        {
            "id": "eyJzIjoiNjQ3NzM1NTMyMCIsInQiOiJDWkUiLCJwIjoiMTAwNTEifQ",
            "type": "inAppPurchasePrices",
            "attributes": {
                "startDate": "2024-02-04",
                "endDate": "2024-02-05"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "inAppPurchasePricePoint": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": "eyJzIjoiNjQ3NzM1NTMyMCIsInQiOiJDWkUiLCJwIjoiMTAwNTEifQ",
                        "type": "inAppPurchasePricePoints"
                    }
                },
                "inAppPurchaseV2": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": "6477355320",
                        "type": "inAppPurchases"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Response

```json
HTTP 409
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "id" : "b42142d7-d656-45c6-ad3a-8a7f19ce6974",
    "status" : "409",
    "code" : "ENTITY_ERROR.INVALID_END_DATE",
    "title" : "There is a problem with the request entity",
    "detail" : "Entire timeline must be covered for CZE. Rightmost interval must not have an end date: [2024-02-04T00:00 - 2024-02-05T00:00]",
    "source" : {
      "pointer" : "/data/relationships/manualPrices/data/0/attributes/endDate"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so that was stupid.

I simply set `startDate` and `endDate` to `null`. Which for some reason I did not try up until now. And it works as I expected.